# Deadlock in Spring Batch updating processed items

Tags: oracle, deadlock, spring-batch, database-deadlocks

Running a Spring Batch application in several servers over the same Oracle DB table, from time to time a deadlock error is produced. The application isolation level is **READ COMMITTED** and the jobs are executed with **throtle-limit 10**.

The application is querying a DB table, processing items from it and updating the same items. One column gives a JobId value, making no possible that two executions of the application are processing the same group of rows.

For example, if one server is querying rows with JobId A and another server with B, there should not be a problem between them:

```
RowId    JobId    Status   value
---      -----    ------   -----
 1         A        0       aaa
 2         A        0       bbb
 3         B        0       ccc
 4         B        0       ddd
```

I've found this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300077/oracle-deadlock-without-explicit-locking-and-read-committed-isolation-level-why), where it is pointed out that probably different threads of the same Job are fighting for the same row. In my case I'm having two executions of the application crashing with the deadlock in the same second. That makes me think is not about threads of the same execution but different executions between them.

I've got the deadlock trace from the DB admin:

```
Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-002b001e-000062c6       177     829     X             51     919           S
TX-004f0004-00001313        51     919     X            177     829           S

session 829: DID 0001-00B1-00000058     session 919: DID 0001-0033-0000080F
session 919: DID 0001-0033-0000080F     session 829: DID 0001-00B1-00000058

Rows waited on:
  Session 829: obj - rowid = 000117C5 - AAARfFAALAAI5iEAAA
  (dictionary objn - 71621, file - 11, block - 2332804, slot - 0)
  Session 919: obj - rowid = 000117D1 - AAARfRAALAAIO+YAAA
  (dictionary objn - 71633, file - 11, block - 2158488, slot - 0)
```

I've found also this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577000/how-can-i-identify-the-rows-involved-in-an-oracle-deadlock) explaining how to reach the affected row, but I'm not sys admin. Is there a way to extract more information from the deadlock trace file? Probably it is a newbie question, but shouldn't the first part of the rowid be the same for both sessions in a deadlock? It is the same for all the samples I've seen in the internet. Here it is 000117C5 and 000117D1, and they appear to be inside two different blocks (2332804 and 2158488). Are these values maybe also temporal values as the others?

Comment: The rowid part is normal; if you've seen artificially created examples then they're more likely to have similar rowids, perhaps, as data would have been inserted at the same time to create the demo. Is the job ID being set by each process as it finds rows to 'own', or is it set separately and both only query for a single value? Are the rows to be processed being selected individually or in a cursor, are they ordered, and are they selected `for update`? Without the statement(s) being executed it's hard to anything but generalise...

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. Answers below:

The JobId is set before, by the process that inserts the rows. A completely different application. The Spring Batch application to read the rows is executed long after the rows are inserted, so no collision should happend there.

For selecting the rows, JpaPagingItemReader is used. Rows are not selected in 'for update' mode and they are ordered by ID. This is the select query:

Select t from table t where t.jobId = :jobId order by k.rowId

Thanks a lot!

Comment: But one thing about the rowid in the deadlock trace. You said that the value is the same when data would have been inserted at the same time to create the demo. If the deadlock is happening over a specific row, this should be always the case, the row is inserted at the same time for both, it was there before any of the 2 jobs started to work. I don't know if I'm getting this part right...

Comment: The values might be very similar - even contiguous - in a mocked-up demo, but not identical. A deadlock affects two rows; each session is waiting for a lock on a row which is held by the other session, which cannot be resolved. If they were working on the same row it would be a block that would clear when one session ends its transaction, not a deadlock. Sorry, don't know enough about your middle layer to help much. Ordering by rowid looks a bit odd though as that value can change, but no idea if that could be an issue here. Maybe manually inspect those two rows for anything strange.